# Can I change the font of a UIButton dynamically in iOS8?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, uibutton, uifont

I have two buttons on my View Controller. Let's call them A & B.

After A is tapped, I would like Button A's font to be bolded, and B's font to be unbolded.

Vice Versa for tapping Button B.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You just need to have a reference to both buttons and when you click on a button be sure it has a target attached to it.

You can get a reference to your buttons either through an IBOutlet from a xib/ storyboard or add the buttons as properties to your viewcontroller and initialize/add them to your view early in your viewcontroller's lifecycle

You can have a 'target' attached to a button either by dragging an action from your xib/storyboard to your Viewcontroller or by adding it to the button once it has been initialized ie:

```
//adding a target to first button
[self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnButton1:) forcontrolEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//...
```

Sample methods your buttons can call once they are touched up:

```
 -(void)didTapOnButton1:(id)sender{
  self.button2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 weight:4];
  self.button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 weight:10];
 }
 -(void)didTapOnButton2:(id)sender{
 self.button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 weight:4];
 self.button2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 weight:10];
}
```